# Jenkinsfile | Declarative pipeline | Run a Job after some specified time (in background)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cron, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a requirement to run a destroy job (which will destroy the instances) after testing. The testing will take around 1hr. So the instances can be destroyed after that, adding some leisure time, say after 2hrs.

**Jenkins file**
Run job-1 
Run job-2 - deploy in lower environment 
Run job-3 - `destroy lower environment after 2hrs of current-time` 
Run job-4 
Run job-5 - after 3hrs

All the jobs should run one after another ***without wait***. And there I am stuck !!

timer - will wait until the given time completes and abort :( 
sleep - will wait until the given time and runs next job/whatever :( 
trigger - will trigger the job but with cron functionality :(

I am ok to use trigger if my requirement can be accomplished with it. 
Or any `groovy code to set` trigger time (set cron time [currentTime + 3hrs])!

Or

> simply - I want to run a cronjob ONLY for one time [just after 3hrs of Now]

Note: I am a newbee to groovy

Comment: triggers { upstream(upstreamProjects: 'job2', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) }

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Will this not work for you instead of waiting for 3 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Use Quiet period set to 120 mins for the last job - Job-5
Groovy syntax is   build job: 'Job-5',quietPeriod: 120, wait: false

Comment: Oh ok. Let me try that.